# Using OpenLayers to render custom tiles

Tags: openlayers-2

I have a very large image which I want to display using OpenLayers so visitors can zoom in and pan. I have tiled it (1 image for the first layer, 4 for the second, 9 for the third, etc.) and I am trying to display it using a TMS layer.

Following [this information](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/UsingCustomTiles) I have it working more or less. However, on some zoom levels, I can not pan all the way to the right and the image seems cut off (even though the tiles exist).

I have set my image height and width in px as the layer's maxExtent.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With software like [maptiler](http://www.maptiler.org/) you can export images to a TMS-compatible format and keep georeferencing, so you can combine this with OSM or Google background images.
Maybe you can get better results with this.

Comment: I can't use maptiler since I need to automate this in a script, and I'm tiling images which are not in a standard format. For now, though, I've downloaded it and I'm tiling other images to see exactly how it does it. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Maybe a different API works better with your custom tiles, http://leafletjs.com is intended to work with TMS, or is that not an option?